# Sonarqube activity page charts missing

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I've saw in https://sonarcloud.io/project/activity?id=ch.ge.ve%3Aadmin-offline%3Adevelopment that the activity page view shows some charts on how the project evolved on time.

I'm using Sonarqube docker 6.4 version and there is no charts on that page and I don't know if it's a version problem or what else.

I'm analyzing php projects. Maybe the problem is here?

Does any one knows what's happening?

An screenshot of the example in https://sonarcloud.io/project/activity?id=ch.ge.ve%3Aadmin-offline%3Adevelopment

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those charts are introduced in 6.5. SonarCloud is running the current 6.5 RC, which is why you see graphs there. Since you're running 6.4, it is normal and expected that you don't have graphs.